# HighCharts not displaying series data

Tags: highcharts

I have a timeseries data which I am trying to display with Highstocks:
Here is the data:

```
{
  "title": {
    "text": "My Graph"
  },
  "series": [
    [
      {
        "name": "Future Index Longs",
        "data": [
          [
            "2019-02-05",
            104516
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-06",
            127260
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-07",
            156291
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-08",
            167567
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "Future Index Longs",
        "data": [
          [
            "2019-02-05",
            21
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-06",
            0
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-07",
            1263
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-08",
            12
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "Future Index Longs",
        "data": [
          [
            "2019-02-05",
            33873
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-06",
            61093
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-07",
            43125
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-08",
            41928
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "Future Index Longs",
        "data": [
          [
            "2019-02-05",
            47542
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-06",
            55084
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-07",
            75256
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-08",
            77786
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "Future Index Longs",
        "data": [
          [
            "2019-02-05",
            185952
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-06",
            243437
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-07",
            275935
          ],
          [
            "2019-02-08",
            287293
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The graph is empty and no data is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Sorry to add this filler here but I am required to add more text to post this question and since this is a pretty simple question, I don't have much to add.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong format on your series, it should be an array of objects.

Like this: `series: [{ ... }, { ... }]`

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wg1vnyzp/1/

Comment: I made the correction. But still not working. Should I use a different date time format?

Comment: @conquester are you sure the div you are trying to render to exists when you are drawing the chart? The format shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I can see the placeholder chart box. But no lines are being displayed.

Comment: @conquester Try updating your question providing more info and code.

Answer (score 1):

To have a chart with datetime axes in Highcharts you have to pass the X value as the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970.

**Highstock example:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f0rsz6cd/1/

Note that in Highcharts you have to define **xAxis.type** as datetime like that:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  }
```

**Highcharts demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kas2oywp/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type